# strcat doesn't append a string into a character array/string

Tags: c, append, strcat

```
ld r2
ld r6
```

So, basically for our assignment, we need to convert an Assembly Code program, into hex using C. Everything works for the add, and and jmp operations for for some reason, for the LD operations, the registers' binary conversion (R1 = 001, R2 = 010, etc) doesnt get appended to the character array called binaryArray

```
char binaryArray[20];//stores the machine code
```

I've got a token loop which separates the each of the opcodes and operators, pretty sure this part works because i it works for the add, and and jmp code blocks.

```
while (token != NULL){
    if (ld == false) break;
    strcpy(binaryArray, "0010");
    if (strcmp(token, "r0") == 0){
        registerCounter++;
        strcat(binaryArray, "000");
    }else if (strcmp(token, "r1") == 0){
        registerCounter++;
        strcat(binaryArray, "001");
    }else if (strcmp(token, "r2") == 0){
        registerCounter++;
        strcat(binaryArray, "Reg2");
        printf("IT HIT R2!\n");
    }else if (strcmp(token, "r3") == 0){
        registerCounter++;
        strcat(binaryArray, "011");
    }else if (strcmp(token, "r4") == 0){
        registerCounter++;
        strcat(binaryArray, "100");
    }else if (strcmp(token, "r5") == 0){
        registerCounter++;
        strcat(binaryArray, "101");
    }else if (strcmp(token, "r6") == 0){
        registerCounter++;
        strcat(binaryArray, "110");
    }else if (strcmp(token, "r7") == 0){
        registerCounter++;
        strcat(binaryArray, "111");
    }
    token=strtok(NULL, delimiters);
}
```

For on of the `LD` instructions, it has `R2` as its first register. So I expect the output to be `0010Reg2`, but instead it just prints out as `0010`, and the weird thing is, it also prints out `IT HIT R2` which means it should've also exectuted strcat(binaryArray, "Reg2");
Output :

```
IT HIT R2!
0010
0010
```

Would really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: what's the complete sequence of tokens that you process in your `strtok` loop?

Comment: Maybe the `token` is not what you expected, just print it out to have a look.

Comment: Do the other registers work correctly?

Comment: Wait, doesn't the loop overwrite binaryArray each time?  I can't believe that's what it's supposed to do....

Comment: Does it work when the register is not r2 ? or doesn't work for any ?

Comment: It looks like it doesn't work for r2 or r6.

Comment: hi, for my strktok loop, i have 
    token= strtok(line, delimiters){
      while(token!=NULL){
         -----stuff------------
      token=strtok(NULL, delimiters)
      }
    }

Comment: I printed the tokens and they printed r2 and r6 respectively.

Comment: yeah, it doesnt work for any registers in the LD codeblock.

Comment: oh, i have memset at the end of the while(fgets.............. so it resets the character array after reading every line.

Comment: This is the perfect oppertunity to start using a debugger to trace your code and inspect all relevant variables to understand what is **really** happening.

Answer (score 0):

After the binaryArray gets built "0010Reg2" you don't print it out and it gets overwritten with a new "0010" at the top of the while loop.  Then all of the ifs fail and it drops out of the while.  So you only output results with "0010" copied into binaryArray.  You need to do something with binaryArray within the while loop, so it doesn't get overwritten.

Comment: I think you might be right, I printed binaryArray right after strcat and it does indeed come out as 0010Reg2, why does it get overwritten for my LD code block while it works for add and jmp(exactly the same except for the opcode binary)?

Comment: I don't understand ld==false.  What is ld? Could it be because you have two lds in a row?  There's not enough code there to figure out what exactly is going on.